# Let's encrypt certificate with NO SNI

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt

I have a site where i have ssl created by letsencrypt, but there is a problem with no sni ssl. Is it confugired ok?

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=watcheds.com

Site looks good https://watcheds.com .

I

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking but the SSLLabs report says clearly that the site works only with SNI.

Comment: Yes, i want to know what to do if i want my site working with SNI.

Comment: The SSLLabs report is clear in this regard: your site works with SNI and even more it works **only** with SNI.

Answer (score 2):

Your site is almost certainly hosted on a [virtual host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting#Name-based) with many other sites on the same IP address.  As such, HTTPS won't work without SNI because the server can't know which virtual host the client wants to connect to.  The raw data in a TCP connection only has the IP address and port.  The HTTP data is all in the packet content, which is encrypted in HTTPS.

SNI access works via HTTPS because the desired site is passed unencrypted and in the clear, allowing the server to properly route the incoming connection without access to your site's private SSL keys.  Without SNI, the server would need to decrypt the incoming HTTPS request before knowing where to route it, and this would require the server to have access to your site's private keys.

And if the server were hosting many virtual hosts, without something like SNI it wouldn't know *which* set of private keys to use...